# How to make this cipher strong?

Tags: one-time-pad, finite-field, classical-cipher

Suppose I have an arbitrary 256 bit number $m$ another secret number $k$ of the same bit length, and then I multiply them both modulo a 256 bit prime number $p$ to get $c$ as follows:
$$
c = (m\cdot k) \mod p
$$
Is there any way to get $m$ back without knowing $k$?

Can anyone please clarify a bit more on that, and also please explain to me why my example can be broken by an attacker?

Comment: If $k$ is unique and perfectly random for every $m$, this is a [one-time pad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad) and thus perfectly confidential.  May I suggest you write out the scheme in this question as well, for clarity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cryptosystem enciphers plaintext $m$ as ciphertext $c \gets (m\cdot k) \bmod p$ where $k$ is the secret key, and $p$ is a prime. It is (silently) assumed $0<m<p$ and $k\bmod p\ne 0$; otherwise decryption by $m \gets (c\cdot k^{-1}) \bmod p$ is not possible. Not told, and of paramount importance: is $k$ used just once, or reused?

- Once: the system is information-theoretically secure, which is the best it can get, but is not a cipher per both the academic and practical definitions of that. It's like a One Time Pad, as inconvenient from the standpoint of transmitting the key, and much less convenient to use afterwards.
- Reused: The system is a cipher, but it is trivial to find (a working equivalent $\hat k$ of) $k$ from a single known pair $(m,c)$, per $\hat k \gets (c\cdot m^{-1}) \bmod p$; then decipher the rest. This is below what the expectation for good crypto has been since at least [Kerckhoffs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle).

---

There's no bad crypto that can't be improved: if we use [OAEP padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_asymmetric_encryption_padding) like in RSA to turn the message into $m$, and undo that on decryption, I believe the combination becomes a provably secure IND-CPA (perhaps IND-CCA2) symmetric cipher. But we have simpler and more efficient ones.

Comment: Thankyou very much, for your elaborate answer! Thankyou very much!

Comment: I realize that even if the key is used once, an attacker (may be a spyware on the host system) can get **k** back if he knows the pair **(m, c)** !

Comment: @VivekanandV: I suggest that you remove the question from Math Overflow, where it is off-topic. And edit the current question here on cryto.SE to make it self-contained (and perhaps more precise): or just remove it. It can't stand as is: questions here can't point to a question elsewhere.

Comment: I have edited the question and also removed the reference... :)